# 2 Assemblies, interface in one and implementation in the other

Tags: interface, implementation, .net-assembly, circular-dependency

I have an assembly A having an interface **ICustomerManager**. The other Assembly B having the implementation **CustomerManager**. This setting will cause a circular dependency because the Assembly A has to depend on Assembly B for the implementation and Assembly B has to depend on Assembly A for the interface. Is this cyclic dependency can be resolved by introducing an IoC which will inject the implementation in an app service layer. Any other idea to resolve the circular dependency?

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to follow the pattern of single assembly with folders to attack the cyclic dependency issue. Since the interface and implementation contain in a single assembly, there is no issue of cyclic dependency.